# Url route based on number of params without prefix?

Tags: angular

```
{ path: "**/:offerId/:specId/:activeIndex", component:EvidencijaFlowComponent  }
```

What i want is to use this component for every routes that have `somepath/111/222/33`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to fully understand your question.

Configure a route with the following path :

```
path: 'somepath/:offerId/:specId/:activeIndex'
```

Note that the base 'somepath/...' is not mandatory. You coule also configure the path like this :

```
path: ':offerId/:specId/:activeIndex'
```

Then check each route parameter to know if it is undefined. And do something according to the number of parameter undefined.